# Return a string array in jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, pivottable.js

I'm trying to return a string array. It needs to be in format:

```
Area: ["0","1","2"]
```

So this works

```
Area:  ($("#output").find('.pvtUi .pvtRows').text())!=null ?["0"]: ["1","2"]
```

but not this one

```
Area:  function(){                              
if ($("#output").find('.pvtRows').text()!=null) {
val=["0"];
return val;}
else return ["1","2"];
}
```

I've tried all sorts of options. I'm trying to return inclusion list for pivottable.js
https://github.com/nicolaskruchten/pivottable/wiki/Parameters
any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need your function to be inline, then you can convert it to an IIFE (immediately invoked function expression).

Eg:

```
var data = { Area: (function() { return "x" })() };
console.log(data)
```

In your case this would be:

```
Area: (function() {
  if ($("#output").find('.pvtRows').text() != null) {
    val=["0"];
    return val;
  }
  return ["1","2"];
})()
```

---

the alternative is to define your function as a function and call it:

```
function getArea() { 
  if ($("#output").find('.pvtRows').text() != null) {
     ...
}
...
Area: getArea()
```